# jQuery selector is selecting all input types of submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working with the jquery-3.4.1 when I came across this strange behavior of the jquery  selector.
The html section of the particular submit button is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Initially, I used the following code to select the only submit button on my page. But, it didn't work.

```
$('submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stopped');
    })
```

Then, I tried to be more specific and used the following code to select that submit button on the basis of an id.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stopped');
    })
```

Once again, the results were the same. Then I selected all the submit buttons on the page and the code started working. The code is as follows:

```
$(':submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stopped');
    })
```

Now, my question is that why this piece of code worked and the others were not working ? Is there anything wrong with the code ? Or was this because I used the same id as the input type ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208050/discussion-on-question-by-atif-bashir-jquery-selector-is-selecting-all-input-typ).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('submit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stopped');
    })
```

in this one you should use # from id or . for class 
but it's best to use class for you select like this

```
$('.submit-form').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('stopped');
    })

<input type="submit" class="submit-form" id="submit">
```

and in your code just on tag should have id with name submit
because id name is unique